# Oracle :Matching row from first and second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, `code` and `price`:

**Table 1**

```
code  name   section 
1      abc       lab
2      xyz      anes 
3      pqr       tbr
```

**Table 2**

```
code  name   section   transaction    id   price    
1      abc       lab       q@abc.com    10   500
2      xyz      anes       w@abc.com    5    200 
3      pqr       tbr       q@abc.com    10   100
```

I need to get `code`, `name` and `section` from the **1st table** and `price` from the **2nd table** based on the `transaction` and `id` from the **2nd table**. If the price is not available for the given code the users can see it as 0.

I wrote a query for this

```
SELECT c.code, c.name ,c.section,p.price
  FROM First c, second p
WHERE c.code IN
           ('00', '00', '00', '00', '01140', '01160', '01180', '01210',
            '01212', '01215', '01200', '01670', '01680', '01682', '00', '00')
  AND c.code = p.code
  AND p.id = 1001
  AND p.transaction = 'q@abc.com';
```

I am getting records when there is a price define in 2nd table but there is no record coming when I try to retrieve records which does not have price define in second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need a left join, but there is a problem, you cant get any results from the second table because you are filtering data from it `p.id = 1001 AND p.transactionby = 'q@abc.com';` so, when there is no price it means that you cant have this registry because it simple doesnt exist. What you want would be possible if the `id` and `transactionby` was on `table1`. To get the `c.code, c.name, c.section, p.cptprice` you would have to do a left join with a subquery but still is possible to not have results.

```
SELECT c.code, c.name ,c.section,p.cptprice
  FROM First c, 
       (select * 
          from second 
         where id = 1001 
           and transactionby = 'q@abc.com') p
WHERE c.code IN
           ('00', '00', '00', '00', '01140', '01160', '01180', '01210',
            '01212', '01215', '01200', '01670', '01680', '01682', '00', '00')
  AND c.code = p.code(+)
```

`c.code = p.code(+)` is oracle syntax only.